# What is the reason for the following error: Error: Cannot find control with path: 'resources -> 0 -> name'

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I try to implement form array in a form, this array contains a collection of form groups, here is the implementation

**component**

```js
form: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  description: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(255)]],
  resources: this.formBuilder.array([]),
});
```

**a getter for resources**

```js
get resources(): FormArray {
  return this.form.get('resources') as FormArray;
}
```

**add resource method**

```js
private newResource(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    title: ['', Validators.required],
    description: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(255)]],
    contentTypeId: ['', Validators.required],
    url: ['', Validators.required],
  });
}

addResource(): void {
  this.resources.push(this.newResource());
}
```

**template**

```
<ng-container formArrayName="resources">
  <div *ngFor="let resource of resources.controls; let i = index">
    <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
      <div class="field">
        <input
          pInputText
          formControlName="name"
          class="p-inputtext w-full"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <textarea
          pInputTextarea
          formControlName="description"
          class="p-inputtext w-full"
        ></textarea>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Adding a resource expects the form element to be drawn and the model to be updated. The latter happens but because of adding the form group the following error occurs, the layout breaks:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'resources -> 0 -> name'

I have tried variations of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679637/angular-2-form-cannot-find-control-with-path) but the error persists.

**update 0**

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67450293/615274) suggests adding `[formGroup]` but when I try I get this error:

> error TS2740: Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormGroup': controls, registerControl, addControl, removeControl, and 3 more.

Comment: `formControlName="name"` change to `formControlName="title"`. Name doesn't exist in FormGroup of `newResource()`.

Comment: thanks but it is just a typo

Comment: my mistake, I have reviewed in detail and in effect I use a name where the title should go, please Yong Shun if you like, answer the question to give the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

As requested by Post Owner,

**Issue**

The `name` control doesn't exist in the `FormGroup` of `newResource()`.

```
<input
    pInputText
    formControlName="name"
    class="p-inputtext w-full"
/>
```

> FormGroup

```js
private newResource(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    title: ['', Validators.required],
    description: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(255)]],
    contentTypeId: ['', Validators.required],
    url: ['', Validators.required],
  });
}
```

---

**Solution**

Hence, replace it with `formControlName="title"` in the HTML.

Make sure that all the `formControlName` in the HTML exist in the `FormGroup`.

[Sample Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zmp89k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)